# Can French citizens flying from Bangkok (BKK) do an international transit in Haneda Airport (HND) with the ongoing COVID-19 travel restrictions?

Tags: transit, japan, covid-19, french-citizens, hnd

Can French citizens flying from Bangkok (BKK) (stayed there for over 1 month) do an international transit in [Haneda Airport](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haneda_Airport) (HND) with the ongoing COVID-19 travel restrictions?

[IATA](https://www.iatatravelcentre.com/international-travel-document-news/1580226297.htm) states for Japan:

> 14. Passengers transiting through Tokyo (NRT) must transit on the same calendar day.

but doesn't mention HND, so I'm not sure whether this means that passengers can't transit or that passengers can transit taking all the time they want.

Assume:

- the French citizen has no tie and no visa/paperwork with Japan.
- international transit in Haneda Airport (HND) means that the route is: outside Japan -> HND -> outside Japan.

[Example](https://www.google.com/flights?lite=0#flt=/m/0fn2g.HNL.2020-09-03*HNL./m/0fn2g.2020-09-16;c:USD;e:1;sd:1;t:f) of an international transit in HND:

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As TIMATIC states, you're not allowed to enter, nothing more nothing less.

Unlike Narita, Haneda's transit zone is open overnight, hence TIMATIC saying transit for up to 72 hours is possible there.

As such, provided your trip is on a single ticket, you can transit.

Comment: Thanks, interesting, where did you read that TIMATIC is saying transit for up to 72 hours is possible there? Via https://www.iatatravelcentre.com/international-travel-document-news/1580226297.htm or somewhere else?

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt Via a general TIMATIC search (Japan -> Visa -> TWOV) http://cms.olympicair.com/timatic/webdocsI/countryinfo.html

Comment: Thanks, that's more complete than the IATA COVID page indeed!

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt That's for general searches. For individual searches you want http://cms.olympicair.com/timatic/webdocsI/spdbmainv.html (Nationality and Destination being the mandatory fields)