# TIMATIC Online (for passport and visa information)

Tags: timatic

TIMATIC Online (for passport and visa information) free airlines web links are off now; specially this:
http://cms.olympicair.com/timatic/webdocsI/spdbmainv.html

anyone knows any different sites or similar layout site links? please help.

Thnx

Comment: This still works: [Swiss - Moscau - Zürich](https://swiss.travel-regulations.com/route-info?origin=DME&destination=ZRH&search-enabled=true)

Answer (score 2):

Olympic was the last fully accessible TIMATIC interface AFAIK, so unfortunately you now have to make do with the IATA Travel Centre (not recommended due to the inefficiency and inflexibility) or doing individual searches on e.g. the [Emirates](https://www.emirates.com/english/before-you-fly/visa-passport-information/) site. Sadly  don't know any remaining interface offering general searches.

There used to be multiple, such as KLM, but IATA has slowly but surely cracked down on them.

Comment: "not recommended" without explanation is not particularly helpful.

Comment: @phoog Added :)

Comment: That's a bit better, but I am still left wondering _what_ inefficiency and inflexibility?  For example, if the user interface is inefficient and inflexible, but it's the only thing I have access to, I may decide to put up with it.  If there is some problem that might lead to inaccurate results, however, I would want to know about that in more detail.

Comment: Removing the links during the covid pandemic doesn't strike me as a good idea, and http://cms.olympicair.com/timatic/webdocsI/spdbmainv.html had more info than https://www.iatatravelcentre.com/international-travel-document-news/1580226297.htm e.g. https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/158740/1810

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt The actual TIMATIC was never meant for ordinary folks at all, but a paid subscription for professionals, that's why. The fact that it's of such great use for us, they couldn't care less about that

Comment: "they couldn't care less about that": I suppose they care a great deal about it for the sake of protecting their revenue.

Comment: @phoog Which they don't get when us commoners look it up for free on various airline websites.

Comment: That's precisely my point.  I can only imagine that these avenues of access to timatic have been closed because the company wants to protect its revenue.

Comment: @phoog Indeed so, and what I meant is they completely lack empathy for the usefulness of it for us non-travel industry professionals

Comment: Nor would I expect them to have empathy beyond developing a product to sell access to us at a reasonable price point.  The same is true of any data aggregator.  If they gave their data away to people simply because they found it useful, they would soon find themselves unable to continue maintaining the data.

Comment: @phoog Fair enough

Comment: Also @phoog, I just now noticed your question about the IATA Travel Centre. It's inefficient and infelixible because it requires you to provide all details about your specific case, and only gives a yes/no. Whereas with e.g. Emirates, whilst general searches aren't possible, you can at least get general info based on nationality and either destination or transit point

Comment: @DavidSupportsMonica That's a simplified IATA Travel Centre, not TIMATIC

Comment: @Crazydre How does one tell the difference?

Comment: @DavidSupportsMonica IATA Travel Centre requires you to "describe" your documentation and itinerary, and just gives a yes or no. With TIMATIC you can check the actual rules (though sadly only with nationality and destination or transit point specified since all interfaces with general searches have been clamped down)

Comment: @Crazydre Thanks. While the itinerary entry portion seems to seek the same data, the results page is clearly less specific with its "yes" or "no" results. I appreciate the correction. I'll delete my comment.

Comment: Thanks for the Emirates link! It's the closest to the easiness of using Timatic of just selecting the destination and nationality with the benefit of getting a detailed answer. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

There's IATA's own site at the [IATA Travel Centre](https://www.iatatravelcentre.com/)